# Correct casting to function pointer that points to a function that returns a function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14, function-pointers

I was reversing a source code and I've found a function it which looks like:

consider this:

```
int examplefn(int x) { return x * 4; }

int (*rtx())(int)
{
    return examplefn;
}
```

well, Then I needed make a pointer function to `rtx()` to do a hook, then I've done something like this:

```
int (*fncptr())(int) = (int(*())(int))0xC0FFEE; 
/* 0xC0FFEE it's a sample of the memory address of the function...*/
```

But my compiler did not compile it, then I've tried do:

```
typedef int(*fnc_t())(int);

// Clearer example pointing to rtx

fnc_t* TRY_2 = (fnc_t*)&rtx;

// then has successfully compiled, ex test...

 int main()
 {
    std::cout << TRY_2()(4) << std::endl; // output: 16 ok.
 }
```

well, I'm getting to the point, How can I do the correct casting without use a `typedef`?

I searched all over the internet and I have not found anything...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(int(*())(int))` is a function type (the same type as the function `rtx` has). Your code attempts to declare a function, and cast an integer to function. However you actually want to deal with a *pointer to* such a function.

After: `typedef int(*fnc_t())(int);`, the equivalent of `fnc_t *x;` can be found by replacing `fnc_t` with `(*x)` in the typedef: `int (*(*x)())(int)`. So your code could be:

```
int (*(*fncptr)())(int) = (int(*(*)())(int))0xC0FFEE;
```

Using a series of `typedef`s (or equivalent `using`s) is certainly preferable in real code.

Answer (score 6):

Why do you want to avoid using a typedef? It makes code so much easier to understand:

```
using F = int(*)(int); // pointer to function taking int and returning int
using G = F(*)();      // pointer to function taking nothing and returning
                       //   a pointer to function taking int and returning int
```

This took me no time to write and everybody else no time to read and understand. I'd call that a win.